# How to find $F = \int_a^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x-a}}\,dx$

Tags: integration

Is there an analytic expression for the following integral?
\begin{equation}
F = \int_a^\infty \dfrac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x-a}}\,dx
\end{equation}

Comment: Make a substitution $x = y+a$.

Comment: But this change of variables doesn't seem to remove the singularity at $x=a$ (or $y=0$). Can you elaborate on your idea further?
@DanielFischer

Comment: But the singularity is integrable ($\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}$), so we have no problem with that. The only remaining problem is to recognise the integral.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Given
\begin{align}
I = \int_{a}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x-a}} \, dx
\end{align}
let $t = x-a$ to obtain
\begin{align}
I &= \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-a - t} \, t^{(1/2) - 1} \, dt \\
&= e^{-a} \, \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) = \sqrt{\pi} \, e^{-a}
\end{align}
where $\Gamma(x)$ is the gamma function.